# If $A \subsetneq B$, is it always true that $A \otimes_kC \subsetneq B\otimes_kC$? ($C$ non-trivial)

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

$A,B,C$ are $k$-algebra and $k$ is a field

($C \neq 0$)

If $A \subsetneq B$, then obviously $A \otimes_kC \subset B\otimes_kC$.

How can I know whether the inclusion is strict?

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ have finite dimension over $k$, I can find $e_1,\cdots,e_m$ a basis of $A$, $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ a basis of $B$ and $g_1,\cdots,g_k$ a basis of $C$. Then the $e_i \otimes g_j$ constitute a basis of $A\otimes_kC$ and the $f_i \otimes g_j$ constitute a basis of $B\otimes_kC$. So from a dimension argument, the inclusion must be strict ($m<n \Rightarrow mk < nk$ since $k>0$).

What if I don't have a finite basis? Does it remain true in infinite dimension?

I guess then I could always use the basis $f_1,\cdots$ (infinite), then there would be some $f_N\notin A$, but the $e_i \otimes g_j$ is still a basis, albeit infinite, and by unicity of the writing, $f_N \otimes g_1 \notin A \otimes C$, would this work? I know there always exists a basis for any vector space

Comment: this is always true $A\otimes C$ is always equal to $dim C$ copies of $A$ even in infinite dimension.

Comment: @ali I see. I guess this comes from the fact that the basis argument still works even if it is infinite, right? I'm not used to infinite-dimensional spaces. I think it works even if both $A$ and $C$ have infinite dimension (though talking about $dim C$ copies of $A$ won't make sense in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This amounts to noting that any vector space is [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module) over its field of scalars. Hence the exact sequence
$$0 → A → B → B/A → 0$$
stays exact after tensoring with $C$, that is to say that
$$0 → A \otimes_k C → B \otimes_k C → B/A \otimes_k C → 0$$
is exact. The inclusion “$A \otimes_k C ⊆ B \otimes_k C$” is exactly the left arrow in this sequence and is strict if and only if this arrow has a non-trivial cokernel, so if and only if $B/A \otimes_k C$ is non-trivial.

However: For any $k$-linear spaces $V$ and $C$, if both $V$ and $C$ are non-trivial, then so is $V \otimes_k C$. This is implied by the multiplicativity of dimensions under tensoring.

(Actually – come to think of it – if you already established that you have an *inclusion* of linear spaces “$A \otimes_k C ⊆ B \otimes_k C$”, you already have used that $–\otimes_k C$ is left exact and only need that its right-exact and the dimension argument to arrive at the conclusion …)